# Visual C# 2008 : Non-invocable member 'Microsoft.VisualBasic.Devices.Ports.SerialPortNames' cannot be used like a method

Tags: c#, .net, com, serial-port, visual-c#-express-2010

can someone help me with this problem..? got this error when try debugging the code..

```
        private void Form2_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Show();
        Form1.DefaultInstance.Close();
        ToolTip1.SetToolTip(ComboBox1, "Please enter a VALID phone number");
        ToolTip1.SetToolTip(ComboBox2, "Please check your COM port number before selecting. Connection could be made for outgoing cable or bluetooth port with data calling supported phone.");
        ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < My.Computer.Ports.SerialPortNames.Count; i++)
        {
            ComboBox2.Items.Add(My.Computer.Ports.SerialPortNames(i));
        }

        ComboBox2.SelectedIndex = 0;
    }
```

this happen at "**SerialPortNames**" in this line :

```
ComboBox2.Items.Add(My.Computer.Ports.SerialPortNames(i));
```

Comment: You probably want to use indexer - `[]` instead of method call `()`

Comment: can you help me to show where should i put the indexer please?

Comment: WOW!!!!!!! Thank you my friend!!!!! i try it and put the indexer- [i] and it work like a charm!!!!! thanks a lot!!!! i really really appreciate your help...thank you once again...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to use indexer - `[]` instead of method call `()`

```
  for (int i = 0; i < My.Computer.Ports.SerialPortNames.Count; i++)
  {
        ComboBox2.Items.Add(My.Computer.Ports.SerialPortNames[i]);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try

```
For Each sp As String In My.Computer.Ports.SerialPortNames
    ListBox1.Items.Add(sp)
Next
```

This was taken from [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yfbcbt43(v=vs.90).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yfbcbt43%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Comment: already try this method and it didn't work or i don't know how this code work...btw, it solve already...thanks a lot for helping me... :-)

Answer (score 0):

You're using it like a method rather than a collection (following it with `(i)`).

Try one of these two:

```
for (int i = 0; i < My.Computer.Ports.SerialPortNames.Count; i++)
{
  ComboBox2.Items.Add(My.Computer.Ports.SerialPortNames[i]);
}
```

or

```
foreach(var portname in My.Computer.Ports.SerialPortNames)
{
  ComboBox2.Items.Add(portname);
}
```